# scala akka http route with authenticate by a token

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

i m trying to convert my spray routes in akka http.

It s really complicated for a novice but i almost do everything.
I m bloked by the authentication.

Indeed, i have a route with a get param token=????
How can i check this token with akka?
My route is :

```
  val route : Route = {
    path("appActive") {
            get {
                parameters('date_end.as[Long]) {
                    date_end =>
                        onSuccess(requestHandler ? AppActiveGetList(AppActiveRequest(date_end, null, 0))) {
                            case response: Answer =>
                                complete(StatusCodes.OK, response.result)
                            case _ =>
                                complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError, "Error on the page")
                        }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

My authenticate function at the moment is (with spray) :

```
trait TokenValidator {
def validateTokenApp(): ContextAuthenticator[InfoApp] = {
    ctx =>
        val access_token = ctx.request.uri.query.get("access_token")
        if (access_token.isDefined) {
            doAuthApp(access_token.get)
        } else {
            Future(Left(AuthenticationFailedRejection(AuthenticationFailedRejection.CredentialsMissing, List())))
        }
}
}
```

I didn t find an example i can use easily.
Could you help me please?

Comment: Are you just trying to rewrite `validateTokenApp()` with akka http?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like Akka-HTTP authentication directives are stricter in what they expect than Spray's.
If you want to keep your `doAuthApp` unchanged, you'll need to define your own custom directive - along the lines of Akka-HTTP's own [authenticateOrRejectWithChallenge](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/master/akka-http/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/server/directives/SecurityDirectives.scala#L188).

```
  def doAuthApp[T](token: String): Future[AuthenticationResult[T]] = ???

  def authenticated[T](authenticator: String => Future[AuthenticationResult[T]]): AuthenticationDirective[T] =
    parameter('access_token.?).flatMap {
      case Some(token) =>
        onSuccess(authenticator(token)).flatMap {
          case Right(s) => provide(s)
          case Left(challenge) =>
            reject(AuthenticationFailedRejection(CredentialsRejected, challenge)): Directive1[T]
        }
      case None =>
        reject(AuthenticationFailedRejection(CredentialsMissing, HttpChallenges.oAuth2("my_realm"))): Directive1[T]
    }
```

And then wire in the route somewhere like

```
  val route : Route = {
    path("appActive") {
      (get & authenticated(doAuthApp)){ authResult =>
        parameters('date_end.as[Long]) {
          date_end =>
            ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: It works well but could you explain to me what is the "my_realm" please?

Comment: It is an optional parameter described in https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750 and https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2617 . In Spray, you could specify no challenges at all when rejecting with `AuthenticationFailedRejection`, whilst Akka-HTTP is yet again stricter. Note that realm is optional and you could also reject with `reject(AuthenticationFailedRejection(CredentialsMissing, HttpChallenge("OAuth2", None))): Directive1[T]`

Comment: realm is a String and not an Option[String] so I don't think you can pass a "None"